# How to turn off a browser's traffic compression on Linux?

Tags: linux, selenium

I'm using selenium to scrap a website on a Linux server with no display(Xvfb) running Debian 9 OS(Google Compute Engine).  But, the website returns following body:

```
<html><head>
                    <title>name of website</title>
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css_interface.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
                    <link url="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css.theme?%23393939%40%233c6ae0%40rgba%2840%2C40%2C40%2C0.9%29%40%23292929%40%23f1f1f1%40%2354bb38%40%23cacf36%40%23cccccc%40%23a6a6a6" type="text/css" media="screen">
                    <link url="icons" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/icons.theme?width=800&amp;setup_8=1&amp;setup_9=1" type="text/css" media="screen">
                    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/big.js"></script>
    </head>
            <body style="padding-top: 270px; text-align: center; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">It seems that your browser is using traffic compression, please, turn it off in browser settings or use another one.</body></html>
```

I don't exactly understand what's browser's traffic compression. But, I've tried following things:

1. used latest version of Firefox and Chrome
2. Set accept-encoding of firefox webdriver to empty string.

   ```
   FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart",true);
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.http.accept-encoding", "");

   FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
   firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);

   driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
   ```

Other websites can be browsed properly, and the same website works fine on my own Windows 10 workstation. But, it returns above body in linux.

Comment: Any chance that you can post the link to the website you're having trouble with? Debugging will be quite difficult without further information. Setting the "accept-encoding" to nothing can be [troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701264/2768231).

Comment: I set "accept-encoding" to nothing to disable gzip compression. That's what i inferred about "disabling traffic compression of browser". Yes, the website i'm having trouble with is [this](http://www.rivalregions.com)

Answer (score 0):

I just can try to explain what traffic compression means:

Traffic compression is used to save traffic and should speed up the website a bit. A webserver handle requests by receiving special headers to know how to handle a request. A normal user don't have to worry about it, because the browser will handle it for you, so you just need to type in your url and go for it. There is a special Header for enable compression to zip files on the webserver and send them compressed to the client. The client must now decompress these files to show them to the user.

If you have curl, you can test it with this command:

```
curl -I -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://www.google.com
```

You should get an output with a line somewhere like this:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

If you see this, the traffic is compressed and you need to uncompress it first. If you remove the "-I" now, you will see a bunch of ASCII art, but no useful output. Curl can decompress it with the option "--compress".

If you now want to disable the compression, you need to remove the header for it. In this example you just need to remove the -H flag and the header

```
curl -I http://www.google.com
```

Now the "Content-Encoding" disapears and you don't use compression. The Webserver will give you uncompressed output. Again, just remove the -I option and you should see the code of google.com

Most (CLI)browsers will send header to use the advantages of compression...

I don't know selenium, but may be there is a similar option to send special headers or you can replace it with curl? ;)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Yes, i tried above steps. Basically, i set "network.http.accept-encoding" to empty string replacing "gzip,deflate", to disable compression in firefox via code, but the same error persists. I'm unaware if there's any other way to disable gzip compression.